# MySQL select all columns from two table with alias

Tags: mysql, database, select, join

How can I join two tables and get all columns without renaming columns when they have same names in both tables?

Something like:

```
SELECT table1.* as table1.*, table2.* as table2.* FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have two tables TableA and TableB

Table A

```
  id   |  Amount  | Name   
   1       100      Test A
   2       105      Test B
```

Table B

```
 another_id  |  Amount  | Name   
   1            100        Test A
   2            105        Test B
```

and you are joining these tables on `id` and `another_id` . When fetching data from PHP script, you cannot differentiate Amount fields from PHP. You should give alias name to differentiate `Amount` Field.

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible.. You must create aliases when you want select from more tables ;)